# Cannot start clock.rb module with Clockwork - undefined method from activesupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a web app that need to do some background job. I have a `clock.rb` file, which contain this:

```
require 'clockwork'
include Clockwork

require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'

every(5.seconds, 'ticking.get') { Resque.enqueue(TickingJob) }
[...rest of the code irrelevant...]
```

When I try to launch the file with `clockwork app/clock.rb`, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/configurable.rb:31:in `config': undefined method `inheritable_copy' for #<Hash:0x000000012b3f08> (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/configurable.rb:86:in `config'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/configurable.rb:59:in `default_per_page='
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/lib/kaminari/config.rb:35:in `block in <module:Kaminari>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/lib/kaminari/config.rb:9:in `configure'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/lib/kaminari/config.rb:34:in `<module:Kaminari>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/lib/kaminari/config.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/lib/kaminari.rb:38:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/lib/kaminari.rb:38:in `load_kaminari!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/lib/kaminari.rb:47:in `hook!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/lib/kaminari.rb:60:in `load!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.13.0/lib/kaminari.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/raph/public/[...]/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/raph/public/[...]/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/raph/public/[...]/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/raph/public/[...]/app/clock.rb:5:in `require'
    from /home/raph/public/[...]/app/clock.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/clockwork-0.4.0/bin/clockwork:12:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/clockwork-0.4.0/bin/clockwork:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/clockwork:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/clockwork:19:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

The first error about "psych" doesn't seem relevant (I get it every time, and I did reinstall `libyaml`). As for the second, I have no clue. Is the code of the module `activesupport` bad?

Comment: if you remove everything below require statements, do you still get an error.

Comment: Hi,Yes, the error is exactely if I leave just the require statements.

Comment: have you tried moving include Clockwork below all require statements? and boot environment to the very top.

Comment: @iouri, post this as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `include Clockwork` line below `require` lines:

```
require 'clockwork'    
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'

include Clockwork

every(5.seconds, 'ticking.get') { Resque.enqueue(TickingJob) }
[...rest of the code irrelevant...]
```